# DbContext Set method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building a mock dbcontext for my tests. But I need to reimplement the set function from Entity Framework.

This is my code for now:

```
public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<TEntity>))
            return property.GetValue(this, null) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
    }
    throw new Exception("Type collection not found");
}
```

**My problem is that I want to save 2 subclasses two the superclass dataset.**
So I make the data set as followed:

```
private DbSet<BaseContact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

**But when I try to access it again with type Contact then I will get an exception because I didn't get the superclass first. How can I do it?**

Comment: What do you want to return for the case of `Contact`, can you create a new `FakeDbSet<Contact>` ?

Comment: Yea that would be possible but I won't to add more to that one database. So lik contacts extending from basecontact and email extending from basecontact

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with how you're going about doing this, but one solution to your immediate problem is to test if the properties' generic type arg against the base type of `TEntity` if no results are found:

```
public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    var propertyInfos = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos )
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(FakeDbSet<TEntity>))
            return property.GetValue(this, null) as FakeDbSet<TEntity>;
    }

    // no joy, test for base class(es)
    var baseType = typeof( TEntity ).BaseType;

    while( typeof( object ) != baseType )
    {
        foreach( var property in propertyInfos )
        {
            if( property.PropertyType == 
                typeof( FakeDbSet<> ).MakeGenericType( baseType )
            {
                var baseTypeDbSet = property.GetValue(this, null);

                var entityDbSet = // you will need to convert FakeDbSet<TBaseType> to FakeDbSet<TEntity>

                return entityDbSet;
            }
        }

        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }

    throw new Exception("Type collection not found");
}
```

Comment: Oke I will try that in the morning. But I understand if you say this is not a good way because I made the context a lot simpler. So we have done this for a reason.